# Consolidating Armatures in Blender 2.9x

Tags: animation, armature, interface

I have a stack of FBX files: one has a mesh, the others have animations, but all of them have an armature. I'd like to combine them into one blender file.

In addition, I just have so many questions as I'm still adjusting to 2.9. In the picture below, a few things arise:

1. I have two animations (actions) imported, 'GuardIdle' and 'GuardWalk', however in the outliner I only see 'GuardIdle'. Why is this and can I see all of my animations at once in the outliner without moving into Blender File mode?
2. I have two armatures, 'ArmatureOld' and 'Armature'. I'd like to only have one armature, and I'd like all of my animations to move from 'ArmatureOld' to 'Armature'. Is this possible? I see I can drag my animation in the Outliner but it appears to do absolutely nothing
3. 'Armature' is in T-Pose, but 'ArmatureOld' is on the first frame of the animation 'GuardIdle'. If I just delete 'ArmatureOld' then it seems like only part of the animation moves to 'Armature' - that is, for example, the arms stay pointed out and only the legs move on 'Armature' after I delete 'ArmatureOld'. It is as if the animations are only relative rather than absolute. Is this possible? If so, and my suspicions on this are correct, is there a way to make the key frames absolute in that they move the bones to a designated position rather than move them by an amount relative amount to their last position?
4. What is NLA and can I avoid using it? Any time I add an animation my outliner adds a NLA Track and [Action Stash]. I have no idea what these things are but I have a feeling like learning how to navigate around them is going to be more trouble than it is worth

[image: screenshot of project with two armatures]

Thank you in advance to the kind soul that digs me out of this hot mess. Getting over this one issue has been a mental block for me for many months and I appreciate your time helping me through it